# Is it possible to allow plaintext authentication only from certain users in dovecot?

Tags: dovecot

is it possible to have the setting disable_plaintext_auth only affect certain users?
goal is that i can define users which are allowed to login over unencrypted connections, default should be disable_plaintext_auth=yes

Comment: This sounds a little like an X-Y problem. Why do you need that?